# Report requery gives error

Tags: ms-access, vba

In VBA I want to open a report, change the filter, and output it to a pdf file. I'll loop through a series of values, changing the filter according to the value and outputting each as a separate file. My code is below. Although the filter property seems to be changed with each iteration, the output files were all the same (as if the filter were not being changed) before adding the `rpt.Requery` line. So, I added the `rpt.Requery` line in an attempt to refresh the data in the report. Now it gives me Run-time error 2467, "The expression you entered refers to an object that is closed or doesn't exist." What am I doing wrong?

```
Dim b As Scripting.Dictionary
Dim rptName As String
Dim rpt As Report
Dim pdfNamePrefix As String
Dim k As Variant
Dim v As String
Dim fileName As String

Set b = New Scripting.Dictionary
b(1) = "value1"
b(2) = "value2"
' ...

rptName = "SomeReport"
DoCmd.OpenReport rptName, acViewPreview
Set rpt = Reports(rptName)

pdfNamePrefix = "x"

For Each k In b.Keys
    v = b(k)

    fltr = "PType IN (""" & v & """)"
    fileName = "some folder path\" & k & ".pdf"

    rpt.Filter = fltr

    ' All good until the next line.
    ' This throws an error.
    rpt.Requery

    DoCmd.OutputTo acOutputReport, rpt.Name, acFormatPDF, fileName, False
Next k

DoCmd.Close acReport, rptName, acSaveNo
```

Comment: Check this answer, it changes the where clause in your docmd instead of the filter:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6614341/access-2007-vba-report-filter-doesnt-work-until-report-is-reloaded

Comment: I appreciate the input. However, I have to work within the confines of a pre-established process, which uses filters. So, I have to figure out a way to use the filter and get the report to refresh and output the data corresponding to the filter. Thanks.

Comment: Actually, I took another look at this, and I think it might work for me. Let me do some testing...

Comment: Using the solution in the question JeffO referenced, I was able to get my code to work and do what I need. Thanks a bunch! If anyone could enlighten me regarding my original question, I'd still be interested in how that could be made to work.